# Circling a particular box in R boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

Is it possible to circle a particular box in a boxplot in R? The assumption here is that I know beforehand which of the boxes it is that I have to highlight.

Comment: Why not make it a different colour?

Comment: Exactly my suggestion - `df <- data.frame(s1=rnorm(100), s2=rnorm(100, mean=2), s3=rnorm(100, mean=-2)) ; boxplot(df, border=c(8,8,1), lwd=c(1,1,3))`

Comment: Thank you but I should have been clearer, I already have colored a few boxes. But apart from coloring I also need to explicitly circle a select few among the colored boxes.

Comment: Agree with above, but for the sake of any digital artist out there who wants to play with R:  Since you know the location and size of the box (since those are based on your dataset), it's trivial to use `symbols` to draw thingies in or around the box.

Comment: `symbols()` can draw circles, but if we have multiple boxes, these may become rather elongated, and at some point, an ellipse will look prettier...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I heartily second @csgillespie's suggestion to just make it a different color.

That said, I played around a bit, and this is what I came up with (using @Marc's data):

```
df <- data.frame(s1=rnorm(100), s2=rnorm(100, mean=2), s3=rnorm(100, mean=-2))
```

Plot the boxplot and keep the stats for plotting the ellipse:

```
foo <- boxplot(df, border=c(8,8,1), lwd=c(1,1,3))
```

Set semimajor and semiminor axes:

```
aa <- 0.5
bb <- foo$stats[4,3]-foo$stats[2,3]
```

Plot a parameterized ellipse around the third box:

```
tt <- seq(0,2*pi,by=.01)    
lines(3+aa*cos(tt),foo$stats[3,3]+bb*sin(tt))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with a somewhat hand drawn look and can do some interactive parts (for example, creating a presentation where one slide just shows the plot, then the next slide includes the circling of the one of interest).

1. use the `locator` function to click on points that surround the part of the plot that is of interest, you might want to set `type='l'` so you can see the shape that you are making (but then will need to recreate the plot without the added lines)
2. pass the return value from above to the `xspline` function with other options.

example:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
tmp <- locator(type='l')  # click on plot around box of interest
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
xspline(tmp, open=FALSE, border='red', lwd=3)
```